# How to make sure a class is always applied on an element with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, class

Sometimes when we use a plugin such as jQuery UI, it will add a class and overwrites existig styles.
But I want to make sure my own class is always applied to the element.

```css
.red {color: red;}
.plugin_style {color: blue;}
```

```html
<p id="foo" class="red">foo</p>
<a href="#" id="doSomething">do something</a>
```

```javascript
$.fn.doSomething = function() {
    $(this).css("border", "1px solid #f00").addClass("plugin_style");
    return $(this);
};

$("#doSomething").on("click", function() {
    // this adds class "plugin_style"
    // generated source: class="red plugin_style"
    $("#foo").doSomething();

    // remove "red"
    // generated source: class="plugin_style"
    $("#foo").removeClass("red");

    // add "red"
    // generated source: class="plugin_style red"
    $("#foo").addClass("red");
});
```

By removing and adding class red, red goes after every other classes in generated source, and should overwrite the style defined in plugin_style. But the color is still blue.

Can someone explain this?

**update**

By adding `!important` may always keep .red applied. But without it, .red should also overwrites .plugin_style since it comes after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The style doesn't quite work like that. This is a specificity issue and

```
"The last rule defined overrides any previous, conflicting rules."
```

*[source](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)*

Basically, no matter which order is used to apply these two styles, `plugin_style` or `red`, the **last one defined** is the one which will take precedence. You can see that you have defined `plugin_style` last, and as a result that style takes precedence over `red` causing the text to remain `blue`.

If you were to switch their order, then red would take precedence (*[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kJuJe/)*):

```
.plugin_style {color: blue;}
.red {color: red;}
```

Comment: `The last rule defined overrides any previous`, I didn't know that. OK, let's say I can't change the order they are defined. How can I apply .red when doSomething is called without using `.css("color", "red")`?